# question about code posted for calculation of risk neutral density using Bondarenko convolution method

Tags: risk-neutral-measure

I have questions about the code (found here [Estimation of Risk-Neutral Densities Using Positive Convolution Approximation - Python](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/44135/estimation-of-risk-neutral-densities-using-positive-convolution-approximation)).

1. The synthetic price in Bondarenko [paper](https://apps.olin.wustl.edu/workingpapers/pdf/2004-09-013.pdf) includes two terms before the dot product of ak with double integral. These correspond to the double integral left of the listed strike range. I cannot find them in this code.
2. Also there is likely a typo in formula Bondarenko gave for double integral he wrote

   `double integral=density - x * integral of density`

   I get

   `double integral = x * integral of density - integral of x* density`

   the code uses a third expression

   `double integral = x* integral of density + density`.

   If you differentiate this or Bondarenko's formula, result doesn't look right. so there may be a typo there as well.

Comment: In his original paper O. Bondarenko provided a link to his code. Have you been able to get it? (I don't have it).

Comment: The link does not work, I just asked Oleg where to find the code.